# Why contact forces behave this way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

So I had this physics problem which goes,

There are $2$ boxes, one $5 kg$ and the other one $10 kg$ side by side with a force of $60 N$ applied from the left on the $5 kg$ box.

I have to calculate the contact forces between the boxes.

With the whole system having a mass of $15 kg$ and a force of $60 N$ applied upon them, the whole system will accelerate at $\frac{4m}{s^2}$.

If the small box is accelerating at $\frac{4m}{s^2}$ the net force upon it would be $20 N$ with $40 N$ going towards the right as contact force.

This seems to concur with the $10kg$ box as it accelerates at $\frac{4m}{s^2}$ as well.

My question is why is it so?, why couldn’t the contact force be $60 N$ with the middle $5 kg$ box standing idle as the $10 kg$ accelerates at $\frac{6m}{s^2}$. Eventually with distance between the boxes and force still acting upon the $5 kg$ box it would move as well.

Comment: It's clear that both boxes must have the same acceleration. Otherwise, both boxes will separate and there's won't be any contact force.

Comment: Please elaborate further on this.

Comment: Why couldn’t the contact force be broken with it lasting a fraction of time, with force in transmission through the the middle box? Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem properly but I supose that both boxes must remain in contact. And, the unique way this could happen, is with the same acceleration on each one.

Comment: So my question is why couldn’t the contact force be 60N with the middle box staying idle due to net balance forces and the 2nd box accelerating  at 6m/s2 from the fraction of time there is contact

Comment: Why the force act on the two boxes as one and not solely on the first box it touches?, I believe this question encompasses my troubles.

Comment: The 60N force only acts on the 5kg box.  The contact force between the boxes acts on both boxes.  Therefore, the net force on the first box is 20N, and the net force on the second box is 40N.

Comment: If the 5kg box had a 60N force how come it provides 40N only in contact why not 60N

Comment: Because 20N force is "used" in accelerating the 5kg box at 4m/s2.

Comment: Now you make me wonder how is this distribution of force determined, Maybe the force acts on both boxes as one and what constitutes within the box ‘distribute’ this force so as everything accelerates at a uniform value. Well, I might be wrong

Comment: Instead of two boxes, consider a single 15kg box, made of a weak and brittle material.  Would you expect this box to fracture during acceleration with some debris accelerating away at greater than 4m/s2?  This fracture would be analogous to separation of your two boxes.

Comment: That seems to elucidate part of the puzzles but am I still correct in assuming that the force acts on both boxes as one and what constitutes within the box ‘distribute’ this force so as everything accelerates uniformly.

Comment: Not clear how the 60N force is acting on the 5kg but makes only the 10kg box move. Can yo provide a diagram to show what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applied force of $60N$ acts only on the $5kg$ box. It is a **contact force** which means it only acts at the point of contact. By contrast the gravitational force is an **action-at-a-distance force** not a contact force, and acts on both boxes separately.

Internal contact forces make each atom of the $5kg$ box accelerate : like a train with an engine at the rear, each atom of the box is pushed forward by the atom behind it and backwards by the atom in front of it, and the resultant force on each atom causes its acceleration. We say that the force **acts on the box** but in fact it is **transmitted through the box**, atom by atom.

By contrast the gravitational force is not transmitted **through** each box, atom by atom. It acts on each atom individually and directly, all at the same time.

The $5kg$ box exerts a $40N$ contact force on the $10kg$ box. It is this force which accelerates the $10kg$ box, not the applied force of $60N$. If there is no contact, there will be no contact force.

While the boxes are in contact they can be thought of as part of the same object. The contact forces between them can be thought of as internal forces, each atom pushing on those next to it. Then the $60N$ force can be thought of as acting on the two boxes as one, just as we say that it acts on all the atoms of the $5kg$ box as one.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the boxes could separate. For example, if the boxes were made of rubber, the boxes could "bounce" off one another and the accelerations of the two boxes wouldn't be uniform. The acceleration of the center of mass of the two-box system would still be a uniform 4m/s2.

HOWEVER, the problem statement contains no information about the shape of the boxes or the stiffness of the material, so the problem implies continuous contact.

One could also ask "wouldn't friction and air resistance change the contact force?"  Since the problem statement makes no mention of these conditions, they should be ignored.

Comment: I have not reached this level where composition of the boxes would matter, it solely involves forces. As I asked previously “ why the force act on the two boxes as one and not solely on the first box it touches? , Anyway thanks for helping!